# I'm having a hard time regexing this data to extract names

Tags: c#, regex

```
CN=Cal Sith/O=SEL,CN=Scot Shaf/O=SEL
```

The string looks like this above, and I'm trying to extract the names (Cal Sith; Scot Shaf) and there may be more than 2 groups comma separated.

This is as close as I'm getting but wrong:

```
((?:[A-ZA-Z=]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,12})\/O=SEL
```

Ultimately, I would like them in a

```
 List<String> FullNames
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the names from following string:
CN=Cal Sith/O=SEL,CN=Scot Shaf/O=SEL

Try with below Snippet:

```
        string sPattern = @"(?:[a-z=]+)=(?<Name>[a-z\s]+)\/O=SEL";
        Regex oRegex = new Regex(sPattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string sInput = "CN=Cal Sith/O=SEL,CN=Scot Shaf/O=SEL";
        List<string> FullNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (Match oData in oRegex.Matches(sInput))
        {
            FullNames.Add(Convert.ToString(oData.Groups["Name"]));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a positive [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `?<=\bCN=)` to assert what is preceding is `CN=` and use a negative [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^/]+` to match not a forward slash one or more times:

`(?<=\bCN=)[^/]+`

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cbCN%3d%29%5b%5e%2f%5d%2b&i=CN%3dCal+Sith%2fO%3dSEL%2cCN%3dScot+Shaf%2fO%3dSEL)

```
string pattern = @"(?<=\bCN=)[^/]+";
string input = @"CN=Cal Sith/O=SEL,CN=Scot Shaf/O=SEL";
List<String> FullNames = Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .ToList();
```

[c# Demo](http://rextester.com/EGKQ63060)